# Libgdx Admob iOS integration not working

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

I have read plenty of documentation, wrote some code, even copied and pasted but still nothing works. I downloaded the bindings from here https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings and followed all the steps from here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx

My project is only iOS and Desktop, I opened eclipse, imported the admob-ios and configured it in the build path, i copied the file "libadmob.a" into ios/libs then i edited the robovm.xml. Here is how it looks like

```
<config>
<executableName>${app.executable}</executableName>
<mainClass>${app.mainclass}</mainClass>
<os>ios</os>
<arch>thumbv7</arch>
<target>ios</target>
<iosInfoPList>Info.plist.xml</iosInfoPList>
<libs>
    <lib>ios/libadmob.a</lib>
</libs>
<frameworks>
    <framework>AudioToolbox</framework>
    <framework>AVFoundation</framework>
    <framework>CoreGraphics</framework>
    <framework>CoreTelephony</framework>
    <framework>MessageUI</framework>
    <framework>SystemConfiguration</framework>
</frameworks>
<weakFrameworks>
    <framework>AdSupport</framework>
    <framework>StoreKit</framework>
</weakFrameworks>
```

In my IOS Launcher here is what its exactly the same as in the documentation. In my IActivityRequestHandler I have only one method that is "showAds(boolean show)" which i am using it to call from my core application by passing "IActivityRequestHandler.showAds(true);"

When i run i keep getting an error like this 
     Caused by: org.robovm.objc.ObjCClassNotFoundException: GADBannerView
        at org.robovm.objc.ObjCClass.getByType(ObjCClass.java)
        at org.robovm.bindings.admob.GADBannerView.(GADBannerView.java)
         ... 9 more